# PHP isUserAdmin function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to read from a MySQL table whether it is an admin. In the row "Status" there is a 1 or a 0. Is it greater than 0 then it is an admin.

PHP:

```
<?php
    if($db->isUserAdmin() === TRUE) {
        echo 'Admin';
    } else{
        echo 'Noadmin'; 
    }
?>
```

MySQLi:

```
function isUserAdmin() {

    $stmt = self::$_db->prepare("SELECT Status FROM users WHERE Session=:sid");
    $stmt->bindParam(":sid", session_id());
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount() < 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;   
    }
}
```

Comment: So is it not working? Looking at it, it seems you have the logic the wrong way. It should be `if($stmt->rowCount() >= 1) {`

Comment: The code you are using is PDO, not mysqli. Besides, there are A LOT of logical errors in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to educate the great folks of Stack Overflow

```
function isUserAdmin()
{
    $stmt = self::$_db->prepare("SELECT Status FROM users WHERE Session=?");
    $stmt->execute([session_id()]);
    return $stmt->fetchColumn(); // here is what you really need
}

if($db->isUserAdmin()) {
    echo 'Admin';
} else{
    echo 'Noadmin'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the number of rows returned by the query, not the value of the status.

If it's admin or user and have a session will always return true because there is an entry in `users` table. If no user exists will always return false.

You need to check the data returned by sql and check if the value of `Status > 0`

Or change the sql and add there an extra check that `Status > 0`